# How to write multiple tables, dataframes, regression results etc - to one excel file?

Tags: r, excel, csv, save, export

I am looking for an easy way to get objects into MS Excel.
(I am using the preinstalled "Puromycin"-dataset for the examples)

I would like to place the contents of these objects to a single excel file:

```
Puromycin
summary(Puromycin$rate)
summary(Purymycin$conc)
table(Puromycin$state)
lm( conc ~  rate , data=Puromycin)
```

By "contents" i mean what is shown in the console when i press enter. I dont know what to call it.

I tried to do this:

```
sink("datafilewhichexcelhopefullyunderstands.csv")
Puromycin
summary(Puromycin$rate)
summary(Purymycin$conc)
table(Puromycin$state)
lm( conc ~  rate , data=Puromycin)
sink()
```

This gives med a file with the CSV-extension, however when i open the file in notepad,
there is comma-separation. That means that i cant get Excel to open it properly. By properly
i mean that each number is in its own cell.

Others have suggested this for a similar problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13007555/1831980

But as a novice i feel that the solution is too complex, and I am hoping for a simpler method.

What I am doing now is this:

```
write.table(Puromycin, file="clipboard" , sep=";" , row.names=FALSE ) 
write.table(summary(Purymycin$conc), file="clipboard" , sep=";" , row.names=FALSE )
... etc...
```

But this requires i lot of copy-ing and pasting, which I hope to eliminate.

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you plan to use the output of, say, `lm()` in an Excel sheet. Can you specify what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, I want the data in Excel so I have the output in a format that is easy to manipulate and share with other people so that they can see the output and maybe edit the format, even though they dont use R. I see the excel output as a midway station between my own work, my collaboration with others, and finally publication. So the midway station has to be easy for me to export, and easy for others to read and send corrections and comments to me. Later i can spend time on formatting the tables so they are nice to look at, and only contain the necessary information.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand the "manipulate" part of your comment. If your interest is just to share the output in a conveniently readable format, I still don't see how Excel is going to help as a "midway station". For writing `data.frame`s, it looks like you want to be using `write.csv2`, which uses ";" as the delimiter. For `summary`, `lm`, and so on `sink()` can be used to get a plain text file of the output, or, as suggested by @Bryan you might want to look into Sweave or knitr, both of which will allow you to display the code you ran and nicely formatted output.

Comment: I now understand what you and others have pointed out that I discern between data frames and the likes of summary and lm, when i try to output them, given that I want most of them in Excel. I was hoping that this was easily done in some way I did not know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`write.table` and its friends are intended to write out columns of data separated by whatever separator is specified.  Your clipboard contains several data types because you are using `summary` which always gives a unique output.

For writing the data values out, you can use `write.csv` on a `data frame` and then open with Excel.  For example, `Puromycin` is already a data frame (which you can see with `str(Puromycin)`) so you can just write it out directly:

```
write.csv(file = "some file.csv", x = Puromycin)
```

Which will go into the current working directory (which can be determined with `getwd()`).

To write out/save the results of the regression model is a bit more of a challenge.  You could definitely use `sink` as you did, but specify an extension of `.txt` on your file so a text editor can open it.  There are fancier methods (`sweave`, `knitr`) which you might want to look into in the long run, as they can write really nice reports automatically.

In the meantime, get to know `str(any R object)` as it will be your friend.  You can see all the objects in your workspace with `ls()`.

Comment: I think i will go with your suggestion about learning str() better, and combining tables with dlply() and ldply(). Combining the tables will minize the hassle of exporting pieces of data to Excel and combinging them there. This way I can export the tables after they have been combined in R. Later on I will look into knitr... :)

Comment: Good strategy.  `str()` was the single most important tool for me when I was learning.  And there's lots of good things in the `plyr` pkg too.  Check out `join`, `count` and `arrange` if you are working with tables and sharing data with others.  I have found these very helpful, and superior to alternatives.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

This will only be helpful if you are prepared to use Excel's Data/Text to Columns functions:

```
capture.output( sapply( c(Puromycin,
summary(Puromycin$rate),
summary(Puromycin$conc),
table(Puromycin$state),
lm( conc ~  rate , data=Puromycin) ), FUN=print), file="datafilewhichexcelhopefullyunderstands.csv", append=TRUE)
```

The problem being that Excel will not read the whitespace as a cell separator unless you specifically tell it to. You can (and I have often done so) use the fixed filed input features offered by the Text-to-Columns dialog interface.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but this sounds interesting. Do you know of any link to a guide that describes in greater detail what have explained?

Answer (score 1):

Your simplest option may be to use the [RExcel](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/) tool, it transfers information between R and Excel.  However it is not free software.

The XLConnect package is another option, it can be used to write information directly to an Excel file.

The tricky part is the `lm` call.  `lm` does not return a simple vector, matrix, or data frame (all of which are easy to convert to csv or send directly) and there is not a clear way to convert the various parts of a list to cells in a spreadsheet.  What would be better is to use extractor functions to pull the important parts from the return of `lm` or the summary of the lm object and send those to Excel using the other tools.

If you can tell us more about why you want the numbers in Excel and what you plan to do with them after, then we may be able to offer better help (you may be able to completely skip excel).

If the main goal is to share output with others then you should really look at the knitr package (or other related packages).  This will not create Excel files, but can be used (along with the pandoc program and possibly other tools) to create a report file in a format easy to share with others not familiar with R.  You could put everything into a .pdf file or a .docx file (the latter read by MS Word and would have tables wich can be edited using Word).  There is not a simple way to get edits back into R, but with the track changes you can easily see what changes have been made and hand edit your R script/template accordingly.

Comment: The reason for Excel is thats the standard at my job. My coworkers want to format the tables, align text, maybe paste different tables together, and maybe include them in MS Powerpoint presentations and other programs of the office suite. Basically they want the full compatibility with the MS programs, MS Office.                                             Writing write.csv2() will work but this requires that i do it for every object. I was hoping a modified version of sink() could do it. I shall look into XLConnect , though the solution will be more comlicated than I had hoped for it seems :)

Comment: @RasmusLarsen, Can your coworkers edit the tables in a Word document?  If so then knitr would still be an option.  If you want to stay with Excel then XLConnect is probably the best option if you want any control.  You could write a sink like function that would convert and append all the output in a .csv file, see the `txtStart` and friends functions in the TeachingDemos package, but I don't know if it would be worth it or not.